# Cannot find bug in NegaMax implementation for java chess game

Tags: java, tree, chess

I am having trouble identifying the error in my negamax (alpha - beta) implementation.

I can make the simple negamax version work fine, however I am unable to convert it to its alpha-beta version of negaMax.

First the simple negaMax version that is working ....

```
public class NegaMax {

    static Node bestNode = null;
    public static final Node getMove(Node root, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        bestNode = null;
        int score = maximizingPlayer 
                  ? negaMax(root, 4, maximizingPlayer)
                  : negaMax(root, 4, !maximizingPlayer);

        if(bestNode != null) {
            bestNode.score = score;
        }
        return bestNode;
    }

    private static final int evaluate(Node node, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        return Integer.parseInt(node.value) * (maximizingPlayer ? 1 : -1);
    }

    private static final int negaMax(Node node, int depthLeft, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        if(depthLeft == 0) { 
            return evaluate(node, maximizingPlayer);
        }

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Node bestChildSoFar = null;
        List<Node> children = node.getChildren();

        for(Node child : children) {
            int score = -negaMax(child, depthLeft - 1, !maximizingPlayer);
            if(score > max) {
                bestChildSoFar = child;
                max = score;
            }
        }
        bestNode = bestChildSoFar;
        return max;
    }
```

... and here the version that is not ... (returns -INFINITY) --(sourcecode ideas from chessprogrammingwiki) ...

```
public class AlphaBetaNegaMax {

    public static final Node getMove(Node root, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        int score = maximizingPlayer
                  ? alphaBeta(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 4, maximizingPlayer)
                  : alphaBeta(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 4, !maximizingPlayer);

        System.out.println(score);

        return null;  // score is wrong ... fix this first
    }

    private static final int evaluate(Node node, boolean isMaximizingPlayer) {
        return Integer.parseInt(node.value) * (isMaximizingPlayer ? 1 : -1);
    }

    private static final int alphaBeta(Node node, int alpha, int beta, int depthleft, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        if(depthleft == 0) {
            return evaluate(node, maximizingPlayer);
        }

        List<Node> children = node.getChildren();
        for(Node child : children) {
            int score = -alphaBeta(child, -beta, -alpha, depthleft - 1, !maximizingPlayer);
            if(score >= beta) {
                return beta;
            }
            if(score > alpha) {
                alpha = score;
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug and this one was quite subtle ... The issue was I was assuming the absolute values of both Math.MIN_VALUE and Math.MAX_VALUE were the same, forgetting about how java represents integers with 2's compliment

I just defined INFINITY as 9999999 and referred to this symmetrical value for both positive and negative infinity and it worked (the swapping of alpha and beta is where these values must be symmetrical or we see this bug)

I think this applet on the web has a similar issue:  http://ksquared.de/gamevisual/launch.php (I notified the author and he replied. He indeed he had the exact same bug!)

Answer (score 1):

edit:

the problem is you are not capturing the move set, the whole 4 deep move set, ie the lowest move set going 4 deep for every piece on the board and then deciding which one to use for that first move of the lowest cost set, you are only finding the very lowest move, which in some cases can be the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th move.  if that move is returned there is no possible way to actually complete the move since you do not capture the preceding moves of the board.

```
private static final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private static final int DEPTH = 4;
private Move[] best4depthmove = new Move[DEPTH];
private int[] score4deep = new int[DEPTH];

public static final Move getMove(Move previous) {
    for(int x = 0; x < DEPTH; x++)
    {
        best4depthmove[x] = null;
        score4deep[x] = 0;
    }

    negamax(previous, 0);

    return best4depthmove[0];
}

private static final negamax(Move move, int depth) 
{
     int newscore = 0;

    if(depth < DEPTH) 
    {
        List<Move> moves = Engine.getMoves(move);
        for(Move m : moves) 
        {
             newscore = MoveEvaluators.evaluate(m);
             if(newscore > score4deep[depth])
             {
                 score4deep[depth] = newscore;
                 best4depthmove[depth] = m;
             }
             negamax(m, depth+1);

        }
    }
}
```

This is all I could figure out and it should recursively go through every single possible move.  hell this could probably work for any depth as long as you have the memory capacity to handle the recursive calls.

Comment: I think he does have a reference to the previous moves as in the getMove() method it references Engine.getMoves(previous)... As such one can only presume that implementation as this is only part of the code.

Comment: The way he/she is using it, is to get the possible moves from the engine they created or are using, not to keep track of the previous, also you don't want to use the engine to find the highest/lowest cost move with engine calls that would take forever and slow the program way down.

Comment: I know my base case is not completely correct as it should not only look at depth but to checkmates and stalemates also. I have it as above to simplify the the error detection process. If no end game state is reached, the points from the terminal node's evaluation is NOT passed back to the caller; but to the previous negamax call (which i think is correct).   What is wrong is i am negating wrongly somewhere. I will try to debug this again after the holidays :)

Comment: Also note that the Engine returns a full set of fresh Moves with all references properly cloned as to preserve the original state of the previous Move so I am not sure why I need arrays as you suggest

Comment: it preserves the previous moves made on the game board, what about this loop where the moves are only possible not made? does it preserve those?

Comment: I recently got this to work with a version of mini-max and alpha beta pruning using same engine. I will report back once I find my bug